# ElasticSearch querying documents with the highest value in a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pretty new to ElasticSearch (here using 8.12) and just trying to grasp it's basics.

Is there a way to query documents from ElasticSearch so that the documents with the highest values receive the biggest scoring values? 
So that for the following documents:

```
{ "id": 1, "rating": 2.134, "prev_rating": 3.321 },
{ "id": 2, "rating": 3.134, "prev_rating": 3.912 },
{ "id": 3, "rating": 4.134, "prev_rating": 4.321 },
{ "id": 4, "rating": 4.434, "prev_rating": 4.421 },
{ "id": 5, "rating": 4.834, "prev_rating": 4.921 }
```

would receive the following scores 
 (*scores not to scale, but to highlight how I expect for these documents to get scored during the query*):

```
{ "id": 5, "rating": 4.834, "prev_rating": 4.921, "_score": 20 }
{ "id": 4, "rating": 4.434, "prev_rating": 4.421, "_score": 13 },
{ "id": 3, "rating": 4.134, "prev_rating": 4.321, "_score": 10 },
{ "id": 2, "rating": 3.134, "prev_rating": 3.912, "_score": "should not event be scored/selected" },
{ "id": 1, "rating": 2.134, "prev_rating": 3.321, "_score": "should not event be scored/selected" },
```

I tried using "boost" in a query, but it just resulted in essentially the same response with bigger values for the "_score".
And "range" query does not seem to score documents higher for bigger value of either "rating" or "prev_rating"
Example query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "prev_rating":{
                     "gte":4.1
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "rating":{
                     "gte":4
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use a [`rank_feature`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html) for that. A `rank_feature` is a special field type and query that score documents based on one or more stored "ranking" field.

You can also achieve similar results with a [script score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/query-dsl-script-score-query.html)

Comment: Thanks! This did have the desired effect, albeit other parts of the query required some tuning to calculate scores more appropriately.

I have another question, is it best practice (or even reasonable) to duplicate the rank_feature fields to another fields (e.g. rating__range) to have the ability to apply range on the same values as rank_features? Because range on rank_feature columns is not supported